# Bootstrap dropdown stops working after I switch pages - Rails 4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the bootstrap menu implemented on my site. The issue is that if I switch pages the menu becomes unresponsive, accept for the "logo section" which takes me back to the home page. Should I refresh the page the drop down menu works again. I am not sure why.

My `application.js` looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require react
//= require react_ujs

//= require writer/react/panel
```

My `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers', branch: '0-8-stable'
gem 'xaaron', '0.6.11', :git => 'git@github.com:AdamKyle/Xaaron.git', :tag => '0.6.11'

# Debug
gem 'pry', require: 'pry'
gem 'pry-rails'

# Assets & Asset Management
gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.7.2"
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'backbone-on-rails'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.0.0.pre', github: 'reactjs/react-rails'

# Test and Development
gem 'rspec-rails', '3.2.1', group: [:test, :development]

# Development Only
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'recursive-open-struct'
end

# Test Only
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.8.2'
  gem 'json_spec', '1.1.2'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

My navigation Element:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <%= link_to 'Aisis Platform', main_app.root_path, :class=> 'navbar-brand'%>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="http://writer.aisisplatform.com">Aisis Writer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <% if current_user && current_user_is_admin? %>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User Management <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to 'Users', xaaron.users_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Group Management', xaaron.groups_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Role Management', xaaron.roles_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Permission Management', xaaron.permissions_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Application Management <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to 'Application Api Key Management', main_app.application_api_keys_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'response Annalytics', main_app.response_dashboard_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <% if !current_user %>
      <li><%= link_to "Login", xaaron.login_path, :id => 'nav-login' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Register", xaaron.signup_path %></li>
      <% elsif current_user %>
      <li><%= link_to "Profile", xaaron.user_path(current_user) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Logout", xaaron.logout_path %></li>
      <% end %>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", '/help_center' %></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

I am 90% sure I have everything included that needs to be included. the console throws **no** errors when I switch pages, refresh a page or - after switching pages - try and click on a navigation element.

Am I missing something?

**Update 1**

I ran the above html through a div checker, no unclosed tags that it could detect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something. It's `turbolinks`. I can see you have it, but let me explain. With turbolinks, every time you click a common link on your website, the browser does not do a complete page refresh, it just sends an AJAX request and fetches the title and the body. Hence there is no `page:ready` event that jQuery commonly is hooked to, so jQuery does not fetch up to the newly arrived DOM structure.

So, here are some options you have here.

1. Get rid of turbolinks. Delete them from your js file and you're fine. You'll have those full page reloads back wich will probably slow your load a bit.
2. Add an attribute `data-turbolinks-track='false'` to your `javascript_tag` call in your layout. That will make the browser fetch the js file on every call.
3. Move your `javascript_tag` call to the bottom of the layouts `body`. Does merely the same thing that the number 2.
4. Use a gem like `jquery-turbolinks` to hook up the required callbacks with jQuery and get it to fetch the new DOM.

Comment: After reading the question title the first word came into mind is `turbolink` and the second word is `jquery-turbolinks`. Nice answer.

Comment: Does removing turbolinks from the application.js have any other side effects other then potential page slow down? I removed it as the other options didn't work. If I add it back and add Jquery Turbolinks do I have to do anything special or is it plug and play?

Comment: @KyleAdams just see the `jquery-turbolinks` docs on how to add them. Add the gem to your `Gemfile` and then add the file in the `application.js` (make sure to require it after `turbolinks`). Then you're good to go.

Comment: I did the first option and deleted `turbolinks` from `application.js` and the dropdown works fine on all of the pages except for my  home page. Once I click it it just appears and before I can click it it disappears. Did I do something wrong, or do I have to do something in addition to deleting it from the js file?

Comment: @Almaron I was having the same issue and knew Turbo-Links was causing the problem, but I didn't want to remove it due to the increased speed, jquery-turbolinks was exactly what I needed and should have been option #1! Thanks!